# Making listview move to last item position

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Am trying to make my listview move to the last item when new items are added to the view. With textview I could just achieve this by doing this

```
Layout layout = MyView.getLayout();
        if(layout != null){
            int scrollDelta = layout.getLineBottom(MyView.getLineCount() - 1) 
                - MyView.getScrollY() - MyView.getHeight();
            if(scrollDelta > 0)
                MyView.scrollBy(0, scrollDelta);
        }
```

But with listview with an adapter, I can't seem to figure out the method to call.
My adapter setup

```
MyView = (ListView) findviewById(R.id.MyView_list);
MyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list, Entries);
MyView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`.  THis will scroll the listview so the passed in element is on screen.  If you don't know the number of items, use `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());`

Answer (score 0):

You can play with transcript mode property of list..Something like below-`lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);`

For more info refer-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL

Comment: I'm not sure that will work.  It causes a scroll whenever a notifyDataSetChanged occurs, which may or may not be when a new item is added.  It could cause a lot of scrolling when it isn't wanted.